# Is it time to use Django 1.5?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django (coming from PHP Yii), and I want to learn it by developing some web site. Should I write it on Django 1.4 or 1.5?
If you had to develop a new (production) web site now, would you use Django 1.5?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Django 1.5 is expected to be released in [around a month's time](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/4EvlunsJ0LY/zh5VBtzfKuYJ), but Django as a whole tends to be pretty stable, so the fact that it's not released yet shouldn't be much of a problem.

If I were starting a new project, I would certainly be targeting 1.5; what's the probability that the project will be "finished" before Django 1.5 is released? (Some releases have slipped, but in general the Django team have been fairly good at scheduling, as such things go.) Plus, I can begin to take advantage of other features in it (Python 3 support being my favourite, though the custom user model is also a great boon).

Then again, from a hard-headed business perspective, I'm sure using Django 1.5 would be too much fun to be trying out and I'd probably get distracted playing with fancy new features...

Comment: Thanks, pretty convincing)

Comment: Pay attention if you want to use django-cms:
https://www.django-cms.org/en/blog/2013/01/15/24-beta-released/

since Django 1.5 is not released yet, we do not yet support it. This will likely stay like this for the 2.4 final release, but this hasn't been decided yet.

Answer (score 3):

Django 1.5 is going to be released very soon. You can start using now.